Estimate of time derivative of solution to heat equation
Suppose $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}\times[0,T]$ and $v(x,t) $ solves
$$
\partial_t v - \partial_x^2 v =f.
$$
Suppose that $f(x,t)$ and $v(x,0)$ are $e^{\beta x}$, I aim to establish a estimate on $\partial_t v$ uniform in $t$. We consider the equation of $v-v(x,0)$
$$
\partial_t [v-v(x,0)] - \partial_x^2 [v-v(x,0)]  =f(x,t)+\partial_x^2 v(x,0).
$$
For the heat kernel
$$
\Gamma(y,t):=\dfrac{e^{-y^2/(4 t)}}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}},
$$
inequality in (2.5) of Chapter IV.2 of Ladyzhenskaya, Solonnikov and Ural'tseva's Linear and Quasi-linear Equations of Parabolic Type implies
$$
\begin{split}
 e^{-\beta y}|\partial_t v(y,t)|&=e^{-\beta y}\left|\int^t_0\int_{\mathbb{R}}\partial_t\Gamma(y-z,t-s)[f(z,s)+\partial_x^2 v(z,0)]dzds \right| \\
 &\leq C \int^t_0\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{e^{-c^*(y-z)^2/ (t-s)}}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\beta (z-y)}dzds \\
 &\leq C \int^t_0\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{e^{-c^*z^2/ (t-s)}}{(t-s)^{3/2}}dzds \\
&\leq C \int^t_0\dfrac{1}{(t-s)^{1/2}}ds 
\end{split}
$$
The above line is uniformly bounded in $t$ on the interval $[0,T]$, especially when $t$ is close to $0$, is my proof correct? I am quite doubtful on this as if we don't subtract $v(x,0)$ from $v$ and consider the integral representation of $\partial_t v$, it involves $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{e^{-c^*z^2/t}}{t^{3/2}}dz$ which is not bounded when $t$ close to zero. This trick seems too good to me, do I miss anything?

Confused, the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-c^\ast z^2/t\right)/t^{3/2} ,\mathrm{d}z = \sqrt{\pi/c^\ast}/t$ for $t>0$ and $c^\ast>0$. Moreover, the choice of $f(x,t)=\exp(\beta x) = v(x,0),$ gives that in the first integral you wrote, $f(z,s) + \partial_x^2 v(z,0) = (1+\beta^2)\exp(\beta x)$ and the constant $1+\beta^2$ can be moved outside the integral, so there is no need to do the substraction $v-v(x,0)$?

I am so sorry to confuse you.  The integral you write is finite but it is not bounded when $t$ close to $0$. What I need is a uniform estimate in $t$. I have revised in the post. The reason I want to subtract $v(x,0)$ is to ensure that the initial value of $v(x,t)-v(x,0)$ is zero such that the integral you write does not appear in the representation form.

Representing the solution as as sum of the Poisson potential and the volume potential one can get explicitly $v(x,t)=\frac{\left(\left(\beta ^2+1\right) e^{\beta ^2 t}-1\right) e^{\beta  x}}{\beta ^2}$ and $v_t(x,t)=\left(\beta ^2+1\right) e^{\beta ^2 t+\beta  x}$. What kind of uniform estimate do you want to obtain for this?

Thank you so much! If we deal with some more general functions $f(x,t)$ and $v(x,0)$ but $f(x,t)$,$v(x,0)$ and their derivatives are bounded by $e^{\beta x}$, can I still obtain the upper bound of $v_t$ like what you have?

Well, if $|v_t(x,0)|\le Me^{\beta x}$ and  $|f|,|f_t|\le Me^{\beta x}$, and those functions are smooth enough in $\mathbb{R}\times[0,T]$, then function $w=v_t$ is itself a solution of $Lw=f_t$, $ w|_{t=0}=v_t(x,0)$, and by the same integral representation
$|v_t(x,t)|=|w(x,t)|\le M\frac{\left(\left(\beta ^2+1\right) e^{\beta ^2 t}-1\right) e^{\beta  x}}{\beta ^2}$.

I think your derivative $\partial_t \Gamma$ is incorrect.
Let $w(x,t) = \partial_t \, v(x,t)$. Then for your choices of $f$ and $v(\cdot,0)$, the function $w$ satisfies
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_t \, w - \partial_x^2 \, w &= \partial_t f = 0 \\
w(x,0) &= f(x,0) + \partial_x^2 v(x,0) = (1 + \beta^2)e^{\beta x} \, .
\end{align}
$$
There is now an explicit solution
$$
w(x,t) = \int_\mathbb{R} \Gamma(y,t) \, w(x-y,0) \, dy = (1 + \beta^2)e^{\beta  (\beta  t+x)}\, .
$$
This is an exponential ``travelling wave'' solution that moves at a constant speed $\beta$ without changing its shape. There is no estimate that is uniform in $t$ except if $\beta = 0$.

I think I still have the uniform bound if the equation is only on $\mathbb{R}\times[0,T]$?

You don't have a uniform in space bound for $t = 0$, except if $\beta = 0$.

Sure, I think what we have is the bound $\partial_t v(x,t) \leq Ce^{\beta x}$ which is uniform in $t$.

We have $\partial_t v(x,t) = (1 + \beta^2)e^{\beta^2t}e^{\beta x}$.
